# How To Remove Nested Navigation Bars?

Tags: swiftui

I have a Navigation view and I created a button to go back to the previous view, after I clicked on it several times, it displayed a nested Navigation view.

[image]

Comment: Remove nested NavigationView, it is should be only one - in root view.

Comment: @Asperi, how do I do that? I have the navigation link and point it to the previous link, that is what I got with the nested link, when I click on the navigation link multiple times.

Comment: Would you show your code or prepare demo example how do you do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I avoid nested Navigation Bars in SwiftUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57102209/how-can-i-avoid-nested-navigation-bars-in-swiftui)